# Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional Type

Tags: protocols, swift, conditional-binding

I have a protocol defined:

```
protocol Usable {
    func use()
}
```

and a class that conforms to that protocol

```
class Thing: Usable {
    func use () {
        println ("you use the thing")
    }
}
```

I would like to programmatically test whether or not the Thing class conforms to the Usable protocol.

```
let thing = Thing()

// Check whether or not a class is useable
if let usableThing = thing as Usable { // error here
    usableThing.use()
}
else {
    println("can't use that")
}
```

But I get the error

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional Type
```

If I try

```
let thing:Thing? = Thing()
```

I get the error

```
Cannot downcast from 'Thing?' to non-@objc protocol type 'Usable'
```

I then add `@objc` to the protocol and get the error

```
Forced downcast in conditional binding produces non-optional type 'Usable'
```

At which point I add `?` after the `as`, which finally fixes the error.

How can I achieve this functionality with conditional binding with a non-@objc protocol, the same as in the "Advanced Swift" 2014 WWDC Video?

Comment: I'm sure this is a contrived case, but it doesn't make sense. The compiler already knows explicitly that thing abides by the Usable protocol. There is no need to test it as it as a test would never fail.

Comment: @drewag what if I had a bunch of classes, some which conform, and some which do not. Then I might want to be able to check whether or not each class conforms. Anyway, this was just a demonstration of the error, it's obvious that the Thing class conforms.

Comment: Ya, if you use AnyObject as the type for thing, I cannot find a way to check if it implements Usable (which is why I didn't provide an answer). Neither answers below compile if thing is AnyObject without Usable being an objc protocol

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can get it to compile by making the cast as Usable? instead of as Usable, like this:

```
// Check whether or not a class is useable
if let usableThing = thing as Usable? { // error here
    usableThing.use()
}
else {
    println("can't use that")
}
```

Comment: This does not work in a scenario that actually makes sense like `let thing : AnyObject = Thing()` Then you get a downcast error

Comment: This should be ```thing as? Usable``` instead of  ```thing as Usable?```

Answer (score 1):

As metioned in the Swift doc, the `is` operator is the guy you need for the job:

> The is operator checks at runtime to see whether the expression is of
>   the specified type. If so, it returns true; otherwise, it returns
>   false.
>
> The check must not be known to be true or false at compile time.

Therefore, the following test would normally be what you need:

```
if thing is Usable { 
    usableThing.use()
} else {
    println("can't use that")
}
```

However, as the doc specifies, Swift can detect at compile time that the expression is always true and declares an error to help the developer.

Comment: But I am getting the "is test is always true" warning using `is`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in the playground

```
protocol Usable {
    func use()
}

class Thing: Usable {
    func use () {
        println ("you use the thing")
    }
}

let thing = Thing()
let testThing : AnyObject = thing as AnyObject

if let otherThing = testThing as? Thing {
    otherThing.use()
} else {
    println("can't use that")
}
```

Comment: Verified, but I found that you don't need the cast "as AnyObject" in declaring "testThing" - anyone check?

Comment: Upvoted because this is the idiom I want to use.  Note the variable you use must be a superclass of the protocol or class you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional Type
```

because `thing as Usable` must return an optional type so making it `as?` should solved the problem. Unfortunately, the error still persisted for some odd reason. Anyway, a workaround I found to get it to work is to extract out the variable assignment inside the if statement

```
let thing = Thing()

let usableThing = thing as? Usable

if useableThing { 
    usableThing!.use()
}
else {
    println("can't use that")
}
```

Comment: This does not work in a scenario that actually makes sense like `let thing : AnyObject = Thing()` Then you get a downcast error for it not being an objc protocol

Comment: Well, then he should do `thing.use?()`

Comment: Then one gets the error AnyObject does not have a member named use()

Comment: Actually no, it returns nil if `use()` doesn't exist.

Comment: Just as objective-c, you would need to inherit NSObjectProtocol from your protocol for `respondToSelector` to work. Sorry for not explicitly mentioned it.

Comment: Ok ya, agreed, but the question asked "How can I achieve this functionality with conditional binding with a non-@objc protocol". I guess the answer is, you can't with swift as is.

Answer (score 0):

swift protocols does not work in Playgrounds in the first beta, try to build a real project instead.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to where you got that knowledge from?

Comment: just got a protocol to work in the playground, maybe mine is newer